# The best way of passing a single command to ad-hoc python scripts

Tags: python

I often write ad-hoc python scripts where I want to: 1) run the script (perhaps by double-clicking on it) and be prompted for the a command to run which executes a specific block oc code within the file. The docstring will contain the instructions. 2) Pass the command via a command line argument.

I want to make sure I'm not missing anything, because I'm repeating this code quite a bit. Is there a terser or more pythonic way of doing this? I do know about [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) and pocoo's [click](http://click.pocoo.org/). But I'm not looking for something more flexible, but as simple as possible (I'm quite happy with it being around 2-3 lines).

```
"""
hello world
"""
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2: print sys.modules[__name__].__doc__.strip()
cmd1 = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else raw_input('>')
# snippets and functions below this line

if cmd1 == 'test':
    pass
```

Comment: I do not think you can get much shorter than this.

Comment: so your goal is to keep it around 2-3 lines? that doesn't sound like a great goal

Comment: Thanks! I thought so. I'm also wondering how many other people do something like this and whether they do it differently.

Comment: Doesn't have to be 2-3 lines, I'm just *happy* with it being a small self-contained snippet I can paste at the top of a file.

Comment: if you repeatedly paste, you know you're doing something wrong... DRY. besides, why wouldn't you write a script for each "command-block"? what do all those blocks have in common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2: print sys.modules[__name__].__doc__.strip()

cmd1 = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else raw_input('>')

def cmd_test():
   print "Run CMD test"

def cmd_something():
   print "run cmd somrthing"


try:
    globals()["cmd_%s"%cmd1]()
except KeyError:
    print "ERROR Unknown Command"
```

Is how I like to do it ... just name "command" functions in someway you can get them out of the global space

you can improve it to allow passing arguments and stuff too

Comment: Thank you Joran, that is *very* helpful indeed. I had done something similar with a dictionary of functions but it wasn't straightforward enough for me to use in preference to my original approach. This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: although its not necessarily more compact :/ I do think it is a more elegant solution

Comment: I agree. Especially because I can now jump to the individual functions  using Sublime Text's Goto Anything (+ @). Before I was searching for cmd1 == '...'. Only 2-4 extra lines? I can't complain.